# Wait for database insertion, Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class (Repo) that is doing some Room DB and some Retrofit calls. For `Retrofit` calls I am using `Rx` and for `Room` I am using `Coroutine`.

Now the issue is on one button click I have to do perform both DB and API calls.

1. Update the *some report* in **DB**
2. Upload Images on a **server**
3. send the *report* to the **server**
4. upate *report* in the **DB**

Because of the mix of RX and Coroutine, I am unable to make some sequential calls. As above mentioned steps MUST BE **SEQUENTIAL**. but the first step takes time to execute and therefore overwrites the data of the last step.

I want to make sure the first step is done before doing other stuff.

Here is some code I am using

```
fun submit(
    report : Report,
    images: List<Image>,
    comment: List<Comments>
): Completable {

   var completable: Completable

    runBlocking {
    roomRepo.saveReport(report, images, comment)
   }
      /////////////// Here I need to wait for the above to finish

        val analysisImageList = uploadImages(images)

        completable = myAPi.putAnalysisList(analysisResponse).doOnComplete {
            roomRepo.updateReportStatus(report.id, Pending)
        }.applyNetworkSchedulersCompletable()

    return completable
}
```

also, this is what `saveReport` looks like

```
suspend fun saveReport(
    report : Report,
    images: List<Image>, comment: List<Comments>
) {
    reportDao.insertReportCard(report) /// insertReportCard() is a suspend function

    for (image in images) {
        image.projectId = report.uuid
        imageDao.insertImage(image) /// insertImage() is a suspend function
    }

    comment ?: return
    for (coment in comment) {
        hotspotCommentDao.
insertHotspotComments(coment) /// insertHotspotComments() is a suspend function
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use a coroutine inside a non-suspend function and wait for it without blocking the thread. That's why `runBlocking` should never be used outside a test--it defeats the purpose of using coroutines in the first place. Without knowing how you're using the Completable returned from this function, it's hard to say how it can be properly reworked. Probably this can be turned into a suspend function and not return a Completable, but rather the eventual result. But of course the function that calls this will have to be redesigned.

Comment: I can make the outside function to not listen for a completable but the final result which is just a success or failure. But even doing so I am not sure how to change this function to get the required result

Comment: so you are suggesting that I should make this function suspend? 
but again then how will it wait for the first DB operation to complete before going down further?

Comment: Code within a suspend function is sequential. You just write it in sequence knowing that whenever it calls another `suspend` function, it will not block until that function returns (as long as those functions use appropriate dispatchers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might already be a library for this (not sure), but you can create a function for converting Completables to coroutines so you can use them in your coroutine flow. This function suspends until the `blockingAwait()` call returns on some background thread.

```
suspend fun Completable.await() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    blockingAwait()
}
```

Then your `submit` function can be a suspend function so you can use it within a coroutine:

```
suspend fun submit(
    report : Report,
    images: List<Image>,
    comment: List<Comments>
) {
    roomRepo.saveReport(report, images, comment)
    val analysisImageList = uploadImages(images)

    myAPi.putAnalysisList(analysisResponse).doOnComplete {
        roomRepo.updateReportStatus(report.id, Pending)
    }
        .applyNetworkSchedulersCompletable()
        .await()
}
```